# CSS Table set max row height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set the maximum height of a cell of a css table. There are several stack overflow threads that suggest to create an inner div and set a maximum height there. The problem is that this doesn't seem to work with big fonts:

```
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="table-cell-inner">Test</div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div class="table-cell-inner big">Test</div>
  </div>
</div>

.table {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
.table-cell-inner {
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.big {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ru1dr2y3/

The big class styles the word Test with a font size of 50 pixels and leads to a table cell that is bigger than allowed. How can I fix that? `position: absolute;` seems to be a solution but this seems like an ugly fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you fake a table in CSS, the elements don't all take on all properties that a real table would have. If you were to rewrite this as a real table, the problem wouldn't exist.

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
.table-cell-inner {
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.big {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="table-cell-inner">Test</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="table-cell-inner big">Test</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="height: 50px; background: red;">Reference: This is 50px height.</div>
```

So the solution is to add those properties in manually.
(I also took the liberty to insert the missing table row, if you don't mind.)

```css
.table {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}
.row {
  display:table-row}
.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
  vertical-align:middle; /* there you go */
}
.table-cell-inner {
  height: 50px;
  max-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.big {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-inner">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div class="table-cell-inner big">Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 50px; background: red;">Reference: This is 50px height.</div>
```

The issue was that with the default `vertical-align:baseline` the browser shifted the leftmost `table-cell-inner` down to align its baseline to the rightmost one, which would cause the accumulated height to be larger. (See what I mean by giving `table-cell-inner` a border in your original fiddle.)

Answer (score -1):

```
change your css bit according to the below snippet
```

```css
.table {
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}
.table-cell {
display: inline-block;
    background: yellow;
    /* width: 20px; */
    max-height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.table-cell-inner {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /* max-width: 90px; */
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 50px;
}
.big {
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="table-cell-inner">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
        <div class="table-cell-inner big">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style="height: 50px; background: red;">Reference: This is 50px height.</div>
```

Comment: This is still not `50px`.